# how do i redirect to the intended download page after doing subscription using paypal in Django

Tags: django, redirect, paypal

I am developing a web application powered by Django.Here user can buy images after a subscription and i have create a subscription functionality and i am using Paypal for the transaction.

**My subscription process in brief:** If an User wants to download an image,then he/she has to select the Image and the he/she will redirect to the selected Image Download page with all details of the certain image and will have a button namely "Download" button.

If the user is **subscribed** then he/she will able to download the image,if the user is **not subscribed** then he/she will redirected to the **Choose Subscribe Plan** page and have to choose a Subscribe Plan and if continue then the user will redirected to the Paypal page for transaction.

This is my Image Download template

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
            <h3><b>Artist:</b><a href="{% url 'userphoto' image.user.id %}"><span style="color:#E42217;font-size:30px;">       {{image.user}}</span></a></h3>

            <h3><strong>{{image.name}}</strong</h2>
            <h4>{{image.description}}</h4>
            <h5><b>Width,Height: {{dimension}}</b></h5>
            {%if dpi.XResolution %}
              <h5><b>DPI: {{dpi.XResolution.0}},{{dpi.YResolution.0}}</b></h5>
            {%else%}
              <h5><b>DPI: 72,72</b></h5>
            {%endif%}
            <h5><b>Keyword:</b> {{image.keyword}}</h5>
            <h5><b>Image ID:</b> {{image.image_id}}</h5>

            {% if subscribed and total_download.total_download < allowed_download %}
              <a class="btn btn-success" href = "{% url 'download' image.id %}">Download</a>

            {%else%}
              <a class="btn btn-success" href = "{% url 'subscribe_plan'%}">Download</a>
            {%endif%}


</div>
```

and This is my 'Choose Subscribe Plan' template

```
<form action="{% url 'subscribe'%}"  method = 'POST'>
            {%csrf_token%}
            {% for plans in plan%} 
             <div class="well col-sm-4" style="background-color:#E6EFEF;">
              <div class="well" style="padding-top:0px; text-align:center; background-color:#85ADFF;">
                    <h3>Plan {{plans.id}}</h3>
                    <h2><strong>{{plans.price}}$<strong></h2>
                    <center> 
                       <input type ='radio' name = 'subscribe' value = {{plans.id}} id = "plan{{forloop.counter}}" checked />
                       <label for ='plans{{forloop.counter}}'>   {{plans.plan}}</label>
                    </center>
              </div>
             </div>
            {%endfor%}

               <div class="col-md-8">
                   <input type ='text' name = 'referral_code'  class="form-control" placeholder="Referral Code Here"  />
               </div>

               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >  <span style="font-size:18px">Continue <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right">   </i></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
```

**The problem i am facing that, after a Paypal subscription i am not able to redirect it in to the intended download page**.

For your better convenience i am providing the associative views.

```
def subscribe_plan(request):

    address = UserAddress.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.POST['subscribe'])

    all_referral_code =     MyProfile.objects.filter(referral_code=request.POST['referral_code'])

    if address:

        if request.POST['referral_code']:

            if all_referral_code and     all_referral_code[0].referral_code==request.POST['referral_code']:

                referral_code_user = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                discount_rate = EarnComDisRate.objects.filter(id=1)
                package_history = PackageHistory(name = exact_plan.plan,user = request.user)
                package_history.save()
                #print request.POST['referral_code']
                referral_code =   MyProfile.objects.filter(referral_code=request.POST['referral_code'] )
                if referral_code and referral_code[0].referral_code   !=referral_code_user.referral_code:
                    discount = -discount_rate[0].user_discount

                elif referral_code and referral_code[0].referral_code   ==referral_code_user.referral_code:
                    discount = 0.0

                else:
                    discount = 0.0
                exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
                exp_date =   datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)

                request.session['exact_plan_id'] = exact_plan.id



                logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

                paypalrestsdk.configure({
                  "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
                  "client_id":     "ATZW9RDw2WZezA_EaleCnnlN6uxMmMLmAIf3Sj59OeGd5wpkULPDGLHb2otc",
                  "client_secret": "EOnbhRAetcxUPpUy7l4guvPNzCUbd-kpJR0rukQIQWQI4nZGruvvvCjzyU4M" })

                payment = Payment({
                    "intent":  "sale",
                    # ###Payer
                    # A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
                    # Payment Method as 'paypal'
                    "payer":  {                                              
                        "payment_method":  "paypal" },
                    # ###Redirect URLs
                    "redirect_urls": {
                    "return_url": "http://med.finder-lbs.com/showphoto/payment_execute/",
                        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8000/" },
                    # ###Transaction
                    # A transaction defines the contract of a
                    # payment - what is the payment for and who
                    # is fulfilling it.
                    "transactions":  [ {
                        # ### ItemList
                        "item_list": {
                            "items": [{
                                "name": exact_plan.plan,
                                "sku": "item (%s)"%   (referral_code[0].referral_code if referral_code else "No Discount"),
                                "price": "%.2f"%(exact_plan.price+discount),
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "quantity": 1 },
                                ]},
                        "amount":  {
                              "total":  "%.2f"%(exact_plan.price+discount),
                              "currency":  "USD" },
                         "description":  "This is the payment transaction description." } ] } )




                selected_plan = request.POST['subscribe']
                context = RequestContext(request)

                if payment.create():

                    print("Payment %s created successfully"%payment.id)
                    print referral_code_user.referral_code
                    request.session['payment_id']=payment.id
                    request.session['referral_code']=request.POST['referral_code']


                    for link in payment.links:#Payer that funds a payment
                        if link.method=="REDIRECT":
                            redirect_url=link.href
                            s = link.href
                            a = s.split('token=')
                            payment_info=PaypalInfo(payer_id=a[-1],payment_id=payment.id,info=link.href)
                            payment_info.save()
                            ctx_dict =   {'selected_plan':selected_plan,"payment":payment}
                            print("Redirect for approval: %s"%redirect_url)
                            return redirect(redirect_url,context)
                else:                             
                    print("Error %s"%payment.error)
                    ctx_dict = {'selected_plan':selected_plan,"payment":payment}

                    return   render_to_response('photo/fail.html',ctx_dict,context)





            else:

                messages.error(request, 'Your provided Referral code is invalid!')

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/showphoto/subscribeplan/')

        elif request.POST['referral_code'] == '':

                referral_code_user = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                discount_rate = EarnComDisRate.objects.filter(id=1)             
                package_history = PackageHistory(name = exact_plan.plan,user = request.user)
                package_history.save()
                #print request.POST['referral_code']
                referral_code =   MyProfile.objects.filter(referral_code=request.POST['referral_code'] )
                if referral_code and referral_code[0].referral_code   !=referral_code_user.referral_code:
                    discount = -discount_rate[0].user_discount

                elif referral_code and referral_code[0].referral_code ==referral_code_user.referral_code:
                    discount = 0.0

                else:
                    discount = 0.0
                exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
                exp_date =   datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)

                request.session['exact_plan_id'] = exact_plan.id



                logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

                paypalrestsdk.configure({
                  "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
                  "client_id":     "ATZW9RDw2WZezA_EaleCnnlN6uxMmMLmAIf3Sj59OeGd5wpkULPDGLHb2otc",
                  "client_secret": "EOnbhRAetcxUPpUy7l4guvPNzCUbd-   kpJR0rukQIQWQI4nZGruvvvCjzyU4M" })

                payment = Payment({
                    "intent":  "sale",
                    # ###Payer
                    # A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
                    # Payment Method as 'paypal'
                    "payer":  {                                              
                        "payment_method":  "paypal" },
                    # ###Redirect URLs
                    "redirect_urls": {
                        "return_url": "http://med.finder-lbs.com/showphoto/payment_execute/",
                        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8000/" },
                    # ###Transaction
                    # A transaction defines the contract of a
                    # payment - what is the payment for and who
                    # is fulfilling it.
                    "transactions":  [ {
                        # ### ItemList
                        "item_list": {
                            "items": [{
                                "name": exact_plan.plan,
                                "sku": "item (%s)"%(referral_code[0].referral_code if referral_code else "No Discount"),
                                "price": "%.2f"%(exact_plan.price+discount),
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "quantity": 1 },
                                ]},
                         "amount":  {
                              "total":  "%.2f"%(exact_plan.price+discount),
                              "currency":  "USD" },
                         "description":  "This is the payment transaction description." } ] } )




                selected_plan = request.POST['subscribe']
                context = RequestContext(request)

                if payment.create():

                    print("Payment %s created successfully"%payment.id)
                    print referral_code_user.referral_code
                    request.session['payment_id']=payment.id
                   request.session['referral_code']=request.POST['referral_code']


                    for link in payment.links:#Payer that funds a payment
                        if link.method=="REDIRECT":
                            redirect_url=link.href
                            s = link.href
                            a = s.split('token=')
                           payment_info=PaypalInfo(payer_id=a[-1],payment_id=payment.id,info=link.href)
                            payment_info.save()
                            ctx_dict =    {'selected_plan':selected_plan,"payment":payment}
                            print("Redirect for approval: %s"%redirect_url)
                            return redirect(redirect_url,context)
                else:                             
                    print("Error %s"%payment.error)
                    ctx_dict =    {'selected_plan':selected_plan,"payment":payment}

                    return     render_to_response('photo/fail.html',ctx_dict,context)

    else:

                messages.info(request, 'Kindly fill the Address Form')

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/showphoto/subscribeplan/')
```

and here is the associated **payment execute** view

```
def payment_execute(request):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    token = request.GET['token']
    if request.session.get('exact_plan_id'):
        exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.session['exact_plan_id'])

    exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
    exp_date = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)

    payment_id = request.session['payment_id']
    print "PAYMENT ID is: %s"%payment_id
    # ID of the payment. This ID is provided when creating payment.
    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)
    ctx = {'payment':payment}
context = RequestContext(request)

    if payment.execute({"payer_id":request.GET['PayerID'] }):
      print("Payment[%s] execute successfully"%(payment.id))
      subs_plan = SubscribePlan(plan = exact_plan,user =   request.user,expiriary_date = exp_date)
      subs_plan.save()
      data_added=RefererCode(user =    request.user,referer_code=request.session['referral_code'])
      data_added.save() 

      return render_to_response('photo/execute.html',ctx,context)


    else:
      print(payment.error)
      return render_to_response('photo/dismiss.html',ctx,context)
```

These views (subscribe_plan and payment_execute) doing the whole process of Paypal Transaction.

Now my question is ,how do i redirect in to the intended Download page after making a subscription from paypal website.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the Answer,In my **payment_execute** view i can use `HttpResponseRedirect()` instead of `render_to_response()`  to redirect it in to the intended **Download Image page**.Replacing `render_to_response` by `HttpResponseRedirect` as the following.

```
def payment_execute(request):
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
token = request.GET['token']
if request.session.get('exact_plan_id'):
    exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.session['exact_plan_id'])

exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
exp_date = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)


image_id = request.session['image_id'] #Catching ID of the selected Image from the session  
payment_id = request.session['payment_id']
print "PAYMENT ID is: %s"%payment_id
# ID of the payment. This ID is provided when creating payment.
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)
ctx = {'payment':payment}
context = RequestContext(request)

if payment.execute({"payer_id":request.GET['PayerID'] }):
  print("Payment[%s] execute successfully"%(payment.id))
  subs_plan = SubscribePlan(plan = exact_plan,user =   request.user,expiriary_date = exp_date)
  subs_plan.save()
  data_added=RefererCode(user =    request.user,referer_code=request.session['referral_code'])
  data_added.save() 
  #return render_to_response('photo/execute.html',ctx,context)
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('download_image',args=[image_id])) #Using Reverse and the name value of the URL(download_image) passing the ID of the selected image using `args=[image_id]`,here the `image id` is taken from the session previously


else:
  print(payment.error)
  return render_to_response('photo/dismiss.html',ctx,context)
```